# Using Composer.json file

Tags: laravel

Hello I am using **composer.json** file to load packages into my application however there are some things I would like to know.  In my **composer.json** file I have this:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.x",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.7.x",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "kodeine/laravel-acl": "~1.0@dev",
        "intervention/image": "^2.x",
        "jenssegers/date": "^3.0"
    },
```

I would like to know what these symbols mean: "**^**", "**~**", "**x**" next to the numbers which I know are the version numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They mean that when you'll run `composer update`, these packages will be updated only up to selected versions. For example, if you'll tell composer `laravel/framework": "5.2.*",`, framework will never be updated to `5.3`, but only up to latest `5.2.*`

> The `~` operator is best explained by example: `~1.2` is equivalent to
>   `>=1.2 <2.0.0`, while `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`
>
> The `^` operator behaves very similarly but it sticks closer to semantic
>   versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example
>   `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0` as none of the releases until
>   `2.0` should break backwards compatibility
>
> You can specify a pattern with a `*` wildcard. `1.0.*` is the equivalent
>   of `>=1.0 <1.1`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md